# Use InetAddress in Velocity template

Tags: java, velocity

I'm trying to display the IP address of the current machine in a Velocity template. I assumed I could do this simply by including the line

```
$java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getAddress()
```

in the template.

However, the line is not evaluated and is displayed as is; the log shows a null reference:

> Null reference [template 'login.vm', line 43, column 11] : $java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getAddress() cannot be resolved.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you provide more full example of your template? Because simply adding this line doesn't cause this error

Comment: The whole file comes from the Shibboleth IdP project, it is some 130 lines long and is available [here](https://github.com/uchicago/shibboleth-oidc/blob/master/idp-webapp/src/main/webapp/idp/views/login.vm)

Comment: No, thanks, it is not needed anymore. See my answer

Comment: This question was downvoted because...?

Comment: I'm also wondering: why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/developer-guide.html#support-for-static-classes) it should be done in the following way:

1) add desired class to the context:

```
Template t = ve.getTemplate("q44153836.vm");    

VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
context.put("InetAddress", java.net.InetAddress.class);

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
t.merge(context, writer);
```

2) use this name for retrieving its methods in the template:

```
$InetAddress.getLocalHost()
```

Also note, that `$InetAddress.getLocalHost().getAddress()` will return your byte array which can not be displayed as ip address. It will display array's `toString()` value. Better to use `$InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()`.

Comment: This is assuming I have control over the Java classes? Or how else can I put something in the context?

Comment: @Thaoden, this is a `VelocityContext`. If you have no control on velocity template rendering phase, you, perhaps, can not do that. See my edit for more clarity

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Any other idea on how I could display the local ip address?

Comment: If you do not have access to the `VelocityContext` object, so there is no way to do it.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your help!